# Redirect issue with program output

Tags: bash, redirect, user-interface, output

I'm working with a graphical-text utility(minicom) in bash and I'm trying to redirect its output to a text file. The process works when I type it into the console and does exactly what I need it to. I plan to parse out the output file using perl and that shouldn't be a problem. However, I plan to automate this on a larger scale and when I place it into a bash script I get a short series of strange characters.

Is there something obvious that I am missing? I am pretty new to bash scripting but this seems like it should be fairly straightforward.

```
timeout 70s minicom Cisco -d Albany > log.txt
```

Comment: The `script` utility *may* help, read more at `man script`. Else the first stop would be to see if redirecting std-err into your log helps. Try `timeout .... > log.txt 2>&1`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I have redirected it to std-err and nothing has happened that I can see on the surface.

Going to check out the man page

Comment: minicom is almost certainly not expecting to have its output redirected that way and what you are seeing are the terminal control characters it uses for its normal fancy display. The question is can you get minicom to stop doing that manually (since it clearly isn't doing it automatically).

Comment: @EtanReisner Do you have any other suggestions? I've tried wvdial but it's functions don't do exactly what I want

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? Why are you trying to redirect this "output" into a file?

Comment: @EtanReisner my ultimate goal is to be able to reproduce this command so that I may dial all of the sites listed in minicom's dial directory. Finding the entry in the dial directory is handled by minicom and that  is not an issue. 

From there, I would like to output whether or not a connection has been made to the specific site(see dial directory); this is also handled by minicom. This output would be recorded and sent(probably parsed apart) to a text file that would be easier to read for other users to make sure that there are connections to those sites.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with minicom but I don't think it is designed for this sort of usage. You probably either need to find a different dialer (wvdial sounds like it might have been a good attempt, what didn't work?) or use a programming language that can drive a pseudo-tty that minicom attaches to.

Comment: @EtanReisner I think I'm going to give wvdial another shot; in the event that I need to find an alternative solution, would you have some recommendations on programming languages that can manipulate the -tty ports?

Comment: I would think just about every major language will have a way to do it though it isn't something I've ever needed to do myself so I could certainly be wrong.